# Why should vacuum energy be zero for LSZ formalism?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, vacuum, s-matrix-theory

Can anyone explain why vacuum energy must be zero if we are to use LSZ formalism?

Comment: Energy? Are you sure you don't mean $P^\mu \lvert \Omega \rangle = 0$ ?

Comment: Isn't $P^u$ energy-momentum?